# Why does Jena's Inference API say this code is valid?

Tags: rdf, jena, owl

I want to use Jena's inference API to check whether entities are valid. But running the test below yields true (valid) instead of false. I am a newbie to the Ontology and Inference APIs. Is there anything wrong about my code?

```java
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);
    model.setNsPrefix("kg", "http://ai.sankuai.com/kg/");

    OntClass klass = model.createClass("http://ai.sankuai.com/kg/POI");
    OntClass klass2 = model.createClass("http://ai.sankuai.com/kg/Address");
    OntClass klass3 = model.createClass("http://ai.sankuai.com/kg/Area");

    ObjectProperty pt = model.createObjectProperty("http://ai.sankuai.com/kg/property/abc");
    Restriction r = model.createHasValueRestriction("http://ai.sankuai.com/kg/property/aaa", pt, klass3);
    klass.addProperty(pt, "http://ai.sankuai.com/kg/property/abc");
    Individual dual = model.createIndividual("http://ai.sankuai.com/kg/POI/123", klass);
    InfModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF, model);
    System.out.println(inf.validate().isValid());
```

Comment: I'm wondering why you expect something being invalid?

Comment: And what about the restriction that you created? You're using it nowhere. Right now, you just create a hasValue restriction. It's just a class expression `p value C`. It's also not clear why you used a class instead of an individual or literal here. That doesn't make sense. For classes, a someValuesFrom restriction would be useful: `p some C`. Even then, you have to create an OWL axiom resp. statement that can be true or false, e.g. `A SubClassOf p some C`